# Resources won't load in my scene at run-time in unity 5?

Tags: resources, unity-game-engine

I have implemented a helper script using a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obmgVpmTJQ4&index=21&list=WL) example. But when I use the Resource method in my other scripts the compiler gives an null Reference error. What am I doing wrong.

this is my helper script and how the resources are called.

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 namespace Helper
 {
 public class Resource
     {
         public static string AnimatorController = "System/PlayerAnimator";
     }
 }
```

The path according to my scene is

> Assets/Resources/System/PlayerAnimator.controller

This is how I used in my other scripts to load the resources

```
     private Animator _animator;
     private RuntimeAnimatorController _animatorController;

  _animatorController = Resources.Load(Resource.AnimatorController) as RuntimeAnimatorController;
  _animator.runtimeAnimatorController = _animatorController;
```

What is the fix for this?

I added both of the scripts. Non didn't work

PlayerCharctor.cs

```
using UnityEngine; using System.Collections; using Helper;


[RequireComponent(typeof(NetworkView))] [RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))] [RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]

[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerMotor))] [RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerCamera))]

[AddComponentMenu("Scripts/Player/PlayerCharacter")] public class PlayerCharacter : MonoBehaviour {

    #region Variables & Properties (Private)

    private CharacterController _controller;
    private Animator _animator;
    private RuntimeAnimatorController _animatorController;



    #endregion

    #region Variables & Properties (Public)
    public CharacterController Controller
    {
        get
        {
            return _controller;
        }


    }

    public Animator Animator
    {
        get
        {
            return _animator;
        }


    }

    #endregion

    #region Unity Event Funtions

    void awake()
    {
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

            //Ensure networkview Component exists 
            if (GetComponent<NetworkView>() != null)
            {
                //Ensure that initialization only executes if this is a valid instance
                if (GetComponent<NetworkView>().isMine || Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected)
                {
                //Load in the AnimatorController at runtime
                _animatorController = Resources.Load(Resource.AnimatorController) as RuntimeAnimatorController;
                _animator.runtimeAnimatorController = _animatorController;







                _controller.center = new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f);
                    _controller.height = 1.8f;
                }
                else
                {
                    enabled = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Attach a NetWorkViewComponent!!");
            }




    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

            }

#endregion

#region Methods

#endregion Methods }
```

AND the Helper script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace Helper
{

    #region Referance Cache

    public class PlayerInput
    {
        public static string Horizontal = "Horizontal";
        public static string Vertical = "vertical";

        public static string Jump = "Jump";

        public static string RightX = "Mouse X";
        public static string RightY = "Mouse Y";
    }

    public class GameTag
    {
        //System tags
        public static string Untagged = "Untagged";
        public static string Respawn = "Respawn";
        public static string Finish = "Finish";
        public static string EditorOnly = "EditorOnly";
        public static string MainCamera = "MainCamera";
        public static string Player = "Player";
        public static string GameController = "GameController";

        public static string PlayerCamera = "PlayerCamera";
    }

    public class Resource
    {
        public static string AnimatorController= "System/PLController"; //Changed the name of the controller (new one)
    }

    public static class AnimatorConditions
    {
        public static string Speed = "Speed";
        public static string Direction = "Direction";
        public static string Grounded = "Grounded";
        public static string AirVelocity = "AirVelocity";
    }

    #endregion

    #region FSM Enumerations (Finite State Machine)

    public enum CameraState
    {
        Normal,
        Target
    }

    public enum SpeedState
    {
        Walk,
        Run,
        Sprint
    }
    #endregion

    #region Object Structures

    public struct CameraTargetObject
    {
        private Vector3 position;

        private Transform xForm;

        public Vector3 Position
        {
            get
            {
                return position;
            }

            set
            {
                position = value;
            }
        }

        public Transform XForm
        {
            get
            {
                return xForm;
            }

            set
            {
                xForm = value;
            }
        }

        public void Init(string camName, Vector3 pos, Transform transform, Transform parent)
        {
            position = pos;
            xForm = transform;
            xForm.name = camName;
            xForm.parent = parent;
            xForm.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            xForm.localPosition = position;
        }
    }

    public struct CameraMountPoint
    {
        private Vector3 position;

        private Transform xForm;

        public Vector3 Position
        {
            get
            {
                return position;
            }

            set
            {
                position = value;
            }
        }

        public Transform XForm
        {
            get
            {
                return xForm;
            }

            set
            {
                xForm = value;
            }
        }

        public void Init(string camName, Vector3 pos, Transform transform, Transform parent)
        {
            position = pos;
            xForm = transform;
            xForm.name = camName;
            xForm.parent = parent;
            xForm.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            xForm.localPosition = position;
        }
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code of loading assets from `Resources`. But in fact it may be because of your `_animator` variable. I am 99% sure that it is `null`. First get the `Animator` component like `_animator = GetComponent<Animator>();` then assign its `RuntimeAnimatorController`.

Comment: Ok I'll try and let you know. Probably you're right.

Comment: Make sure that you have attached animator component from inspector

Comment: Hmm. I guess something wrong with the code. I already added that too. Still the problem exists. probably a bug.